# Android TCP/LocalService

Tags: android, sockets, service, tcp

I am new to Android development and am not sure of the best way to go about handling the following problem.

Background:
I have a TCP client running on android talking to a server. this is up and running just fine however when moving to the next step i am unsure of what to do.

Problem:
I have a UI that draws based on a users touch.  I need for the tcp client running on the phone to send the coordinates and some other data to the server. Also there are multiple activities in this process that would be sending data.

What would be the best way to handle this? 
Here are some of my thoughts.

1) A class that would have a Runnable client that works on another thread (I think its is an invalid solution because it would not be easy to use the same connection on multiple activities)

2) A local service that can the main activity can start and the rest of the activities can bind to it and send data to it.

If the correct answer is number 2 I am a little confused on how a service like that would work. What I am thinking is that in the OnCreate() method of the service it will launch a tcp connection with the server. Once the socket connection is established I am a bit unsure of how to actually keep in communication with the service and give it the data it needs to send over the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would start the service with `startService()`. Include in the `Intent` extras that contain your data to send to the server. The service would retrieve these extras in `onStartCommand()` and would have a background thread actually send the data.

Be sure to stop the service when you are done with it.

Comment: I understand up to that part. However this needs to support ongoing communication. Is adding that as easy as creating a method something like "public void writeToServer(String data)" in the service. then call that directly from the activity?

Comment: @kelab: You keep sending new commands via `startService()`. You can call `startService()` as many times as is necessary to send as many commands as is necessary. You can also call `bindService()` to have your service expose a richer API, but this tends to more tightly tie your activity and service together, making things more challenging for configuration changes (e.g., user rotates the screen).